# How to query an XML document with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Lets say I have the following XML document:

```
<response>
   <businessEntity>
      <ABN>
         <identifierValue></identifierValue> 
         <isCurrentIndicator></isCurrentIndicator> 
         <replacedIdentifierValue xsi:nil="true" /> 
         <replacedFrom></replacedFrom> 
      </ABN>
      <entityStatus>
         <entityStatusCode> </entityStatusCode> 
         <effectiveFrom></effectiveFrom> 
         <effectiveTo></effectiveTo> 
      </entityStatus>
      <entityType>
         <entityTypeCode> </entityTypeCode> 
         <entityDescription> </entityDescription> 
      </entityType>
      <goodsAndServicesTax>
          <effectiveFrom></effectiveFrom> 
          <effectiveTo></effectiveTo> 
      </goodsAndServicesTax>
      <legalName>
          <givenName> </givenName> 
          <otherGivenName /> 
          <familyName> </familyName> 
          <effectiveFrom></effectiveFrom> 
          <effectiveTo></effectiveTo> 
      </legalName>
      <mainBusinessPhysicalAddress>
          <stateCode> </stateCode> 
          <postcode></postcode> 
          <effectiveFrom></effectiveFrom> 
          <effectiveTo></effectiveTo> 
      </mainBusinessPhysicalAddress>
   </businessEntity>
</response>
```

If I want to get the givenName and familyName for example I can do this:

```
var businesses = doc.Descendants(ns + "businessEntity")
             .Elements(ns + "legalName")
             .Select(node => new
             {
                 effectiveFrom = node.Element(ns + "effectiveFrom").Value,
                 givenName = node.Element(ns + "givenName").Value,
                 familyName = node.Element(ns + "familyName").Value,
             }).ToList();
```

which I then can access and populate a table with, I am not sure how to query the whole document though and get all the nodes I want, like ABN and entityType for example. Do I need to create a list and replicate part of the code for each sibling to legalName?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that each subelement occurs only once you can try this approach:

```
var businesses = (
    from node in doc.Descendants(ns + "businessEntity")
    let legalName = node.Element(ns + "legalName")
    let abn = node.Element(ns + "ABN")
    // etc...
    select new
    {
        LegalName = new
        {
            EffectiveFrom = (string)legalName.Element(ns + "effectiveFrom"),
            GivenName = (string)legalName.Element(ns + "givenName"),
            FamilyName = (string)legalName.Element(ns + "familyName"),
        },
        Abn = new
        {
            IdentifierValue = (string)abn.Element(ns + "identifierValue"),
            IsCurrentIndicator = (string)abn.Element(ns + "isCurrentIndicator"),
            ReplacedFrom = (string)abn.Element(ns + "replacedFrom"),
        },
        // etc...
    }).ToList();


Console.WriteLine(businesses[0].LegalName.GivenName);
Console.WriteLine(businesses[0].Abn.IsCurrentIndicator);
```

You may also want to consider using concrete types instead of anonyous types if this data is going to be used outside the method where you are parsing the XML.

Comment: thanks, work like expected, an error is raised if a value is empty though, how do I best handle this?

Comment: @Nick: It depends on which part is "empty" and what specifically you mean by "empty" (completely missing? present but containing the empty string?). You could try changing `foo.Element(...).Value` to `(string)foo.Element(...)`. If that doesn't work, please give more details of what is empty and in what way it is empty. The simplest way to explain it is to post the XML document where it fails, the exact code you tried and the error message you got. If you can't do that you can try to explain it in words.

Comment: if for example givenname contains no value I get nullreferenceexception was unhandled by code

Comment: Updated answer to handle this specific case. In future please remember to mention this at the beginning as extending the requirements all the time makes it difficult to provide an answer quickly.